# spatie/image-optimizer How to optimize and leave all image metadata?

Tags: php, laravel, image, jpeg, image-optimization

How to optimize jpg images with `spatie/image-optimizer` and leave all metadata from the image?

```
    return (new OptimizerChain())
        ->addOptimizer(new Jpegoptim([
            $jpegQuality,
            '--strip-all',
            '--all-progressive',
        ]))
```

Sure you can delete the `--strip-all` line, but it would be not correct, because this is the vendor file.

Comment: You can use `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\LaravelImageOptimizer\ImageOptimizerServiceProvider"` to publish the config file and remove it yourself

Answer (score -1):

**use ImageOptimizer;**

*// the image will be replaced with an optimized version which should be smaller*

```
ImageOptimizer::optimize($pathToImage);
```

*// if you use a second parameter the package will not modify the original*

```
ImageOptimizer::optimize($pathToImage, $pathToOptimizedImage);
```